# Unable to delete a file in git

Tags: git, unicode

I have something a weird behaviour with a file containing unicode character:

```
Spécifications fonctionnelles v1.4.pdf
```

I don't know what happened but since a few hour I have the following git status message:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    "doc/fr/Sp\351cifications fonctionnelles v1.4.pdf"

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

The file is there yet and if I try to delete it I have the following listing:

```
       deleted:    "Sp\303\251cifications fonctionnelles ERytmo v1.4.pdf"
       deleted:    "Sp\351cifications fonctionnelles ERytmo v1.4.pdf"
```

I suspect then a change in the encoding but my problem is not there I just like to clean up my repository state but `git reset --hard HEAD` is effectless.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try the following command: `git rm file1 file2` in order to remove the deleted files from your index?

Answer (score 1):

Try `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached`

Taken from [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html). "If all you really want to do is to remove from the index the files that are no longer present in the working tree (perhaps because your working tree is dirty so that you cannot use git commit -a), use the following command" ^